# Editing the finally block of try-catch in Java ASM bytecode

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I have a java class and I want to add some custom instruction inside each finally block.
I've tried working with Java ASM library.
I've tried to iterate each method and then iterate through each TryCatchBlockNode and take the handle label and insert the instruction there.

```
List<MethodNode> methods = (List<MethodNode>) classNode.methods;
    for (MethodNode method : methods) {
        List<TryCatchBlockNode> tryCatchBlocks = method.tryCatchBlocks;

        for (int i = 0; i < tryCatchBlocks.size(); i++) {
                TryCatchBlockNode tryCatchBlockNode = (TryCatchBlockNode) method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i);
                if (tryCatchBlockNode.type == null) {
                    InsnList tmpInsn = new InsnList();
                    tmpInsn.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
                    tmpInsn.add(new LdcInsnNode("AAAA"));
                    tmpInsn.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
                    method.instructions.insert(tryCatchBlockNode.handler, tmpInsn);
                }
        }
     }
```

How could I insert some custom code inside each finally block?

Edited:
The code above works but the refactor is not as expected:

Input code was:

```
    try {
        lr.abort();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("throwable");
    }
```

Decompiled code with IntelliJ
Output:

```
try {
    lr.abort();
} catch (Throwable var3) {
    System.out.println("AAAA");
    System.out.println("throwable");
    throw var3;
}

System.out.println("throwable");
System.out.println("Goodbye!");
```

Comment: Don't do it if you can solve your problem in a more direct way. Also, wich do you want to modify? precompiled classes (e.g. from an existing jar) or for all your codebase at compilation time?

Comment: The problem is much more complex and this was the only solution we found. I have a precompiled class and we need to refactor the try-catch-finally block, as we need to check the instance of the thrown exception.

Comment: _"a java class"_, _"a precompiled class"_, how many classes you should to patch? a single one? anyway (one or many) you could try to decompile the module.

Comment: We have a single java class but this class gets uploaded on the server by the client and it needs to be an automatic process.

Comment: There are no `finally` blocks in bytecode. There are just exception handlers. A `null` type implies “catch-all”, which could be a `finally` block or a close operation of a `try(…)` statement or the release of a `synchronized` block or a `catch(Throwable …)` if the compiler decided to compile it that way. In either case, the `start`, `end`, and `handler` labels are never `null`, this has not been foreseen by the class reader (nor the class writer) at all. If you encounter `null` values, your application must have created the nodes that way itself or overwritten the fields at some point.

Comment: @Holger yes you are right, it's not null, I've updated my question :)

Comment: Think of what will happen when you repeatedly tell someone to *insert after a fixpoint*, i.e. “insert A after X” → `[X, A]`, “insert B after X” → `[X, B, A]`, “insert C after X” → `[X, C, B, A]`, my commands were in the order A, B, C, but the result is X followed by C, B, A…

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatedly inserting an instruction node after the label node, where you actually want to insert the instruction node after the node you’ve just inserted.

The general pattern is

- insert A after X
  resulting in [X, A]
- insert B after X
  resulting in [X, B, A]
- insert C after X
  resulting [X, C, B, A]

ending up with the opposite order of your insert instructions.

There are different ways to solve this

1. Just use the opposite order

   ```java
   TryCatchBlockNode tryCatchBlockNode = method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i);
   if(tryCatchBlockNode.type == null) {
       LabelNode h = tryCatchBlockNode.handler;
       method.instructions.insert(h, new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
               "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
       method.instructions.insert(h, new LdcInsnNode("AAAA"));
       method.instructions.insert(h, new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC,
               "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
   }
   ```

   This is simple but becomes hard to read the more instructions you have to insert.
2. Don’t use a fixpoint, but the previously inserted node

   ```java
   TryCatchBlockNode tryCatchBlockNode = method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i);
   if(tryCatchBlockNode.type == null) {
       AbstractInsnNode after = tryCatchBlockNode.handler;
       method.instructions.insert(after, after = new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC,
               "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
       method.instructions.insert(after, after = new LdcInsnNode("AAAA"));
       method.instructions.insert(after, after = new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
               "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
   }
   ```

   This allows to specify the instructions in the intended result order, but requires a changing variable.
3. Get the next node after the label and use `insertBefore` instead

   ```java
   TryCatchBlockNode tryCatchBlockNode = method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i);
   if(tryCatchBlockNode.type == null) {
       AbstractInsnNode before = tryCatchBlockNode.handler.getNext();
       method.instructions.insertBefore(before, new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC,
               "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
       method.instructions.insertBefore(before, new LdcInsnNode("AAAA"));
       method.instructions.insertBefore(before, new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
               "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
   }
   ```

   Works smoothly here, since exception handlers can’t be empty. So there must be a subsequent node, which we can refer to. But it might not be applicable in other scenarios.

---

You may also use instruction lists and insert them as a single entity.

```java
static InsnList printStatement() {
    InsnList print = new InsnList();
    print.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC,
            "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
    print.add(new LdcInsnNode("AAAA"));
    print.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
            "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"));
    return print;
}
```

```java
TryCatchBlockNode tryCatchBlockNode = method.tryCatchBlocks.get(i);
if(tryCatchBlockNode.type == null) {
    method.instructions.insert(tryCatchBlockNode.handler, printStatement());
}
```

Such building blocks are easier to maintain. It’s important to keep in mind that this will transfer the nodes from one list to another, so you have to call the factory method again each time you need to insert the sequence, instead of reusing the `InsnList` object.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested here but after decompiling it in IntelliJ the output it' not what actually the expected. I've updated my question with your suggestion and the output of the decompile.

Comment: Don’t change the question, this answer is responding to. If you have a new question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).